# systematic sampling and probability sample

Tags: self-study, sampling

The registrar has the list of all students in the university, in alphabetical order. Among 25,000 students in the university, the investigator proposes to choose a number at random from 1 to 100. Starting from that number, every 100th person is included in the sample.
i) This is an example of systematic sampling
ii) Since the names are in alphabetical order, resulting sample is not a probability sample

It is a systematic sampling because they choose every 100 person after the 1st random is choosen.
Is ii) true too?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site, Andrew. This looks like a question from the homework (so I tagged it [`self-study`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study)). We cannot answer that for you, but we can try to guide you towards the answer. It would help, in your case, if you provided the definition of the systematic sample that your book/your instructor gave you, and state something along the lines of "I see this part of the definition in my example, but I don't see that part". Or something.